# ¿como hago que las etiquetas a del nav cambien de color al llegar a determinada altura con el scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quiero que cuando llegue al section con el id="content-4" cambien el color de las etiquetas "a".

```html
<nav id="nav">
        <a href="#content-1">Up</a>
        <a href="#content-2">About</a>
        <a href="#content-3">Projects</a>
        <a href="#content-4">Contact</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hola bienvenido a SO, por favor explica el problema especificamente, ademas  de subir un [mcve], lectura recomendada [ask]

Comment: Con la API de JavaScript [Interseption observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te reproduzco un ejemplo para cambiar el color de fondo del nav.

Te puse también una etiqueta de párrafo donde se ve el resultado del scroll en tiempo real para que entiendas como funciona mejor.

Espero que te sirva

```js
const nav = document.querySelector("nav");

window.onscroll = function() {
    let scrollY = this.scrollY;
    document.querySelector("p").innerHTML = scrollY;
    if(scrollY > 500){
        nav.style.backgroundColor = "white";
     } else {
         nav.style.backgroundColor = "black"; 
    }
};
```

```css
nav{
    position: fixed;
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    transition: 1s;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    -moz-transition: 1s;
    -ms-transition: 1s;
    -o-transition: 1s;
}

nav a {
    color: gray;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 10px; 
}

.container {
    height: 4000px;
}

p {
    position: fixed;
    top: 300px;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
        <a href="">Ejemplo uno</a>
        <a href="">Ejemplo dos</a>
        <a href="">Ejemplo tres</a>
        <a href="">Ejemplo cuatro</a>

    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <p id="resultado"></p>
    </div>
```

Comment: si bien no fue exactamente lo que queria, modificar el color de los textos de las etiquetas "a" del nav cuando llegue a determinada altura, con el codigo que me brindaste, se me ocurrio aplicar un nav.style.filter = "invert(100%)"; en el if, y me fue util. Gracias.

Comment: @casal entonces solo necesitas cambiar el selector y aplicar el fontSize Color para toda la lista que te genere el querySelector

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo aplicado a tu contenedor, donde obtenemos el elemnto **nav** y obtenemos la posición cada que se detone el evento **scroll**, al obtener dichas coordenadas asignamos el rango en el que se cambiaran los estilos del elemento, esto gracias a la función **getBoundingClientRect()**, es la que nos otorga las coordenadas. Observa que al pasar por el rango de coordenadas especificadas en el **if** el *background cambia a color gris*, cuando sale de las coordenadas pasa de nuevo a color blanco.

```js
//ESCUCHAMOS EL EVENTO SCROLL DEL DOCUMENTO
document.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
//OBTENEMOS EL ELEMENTO CONTENEDOR SOBRE EL QUE OBTENEMOS LAS COORDENADAS
  let elem = document.querySelector('#nav');
  //CON LA FUNCION getBoundingClientRect() OBTENEMOS LAS COORDENADAS DE POSICION DEL ELEMENTO, ESTA SE EJECUTARA CADA QUE HAGAMOS SCROLL
  let rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  //OBSERVAMOS EN CONSOLA LAS COORDENADAS Y EN BASE A ELLAS HACEMOS EL CALCULO Y INDICAMOS EL RANGO EN EL IF
  console.log("x: " + rect.x);
  console.log("y: " + rect.y);
  console.log(elem);
  if (rect.x >= 12.989936828613281 && rect.y <= 100.0000000000000000) {
  //CAMBIAMOS LOS ESTILOS CUANDO LOS ELEMENTOS SE ENCUENTREN DENTRO DEL RANGO ESPECIFICADO
    elem.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
  } else {
    elem.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  }
});
```

```css
#container {
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid;
}

#container2 {
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  Contendor 1
</div>
<div id="container2">
  <nav id="nav">
    <a href="#content-1">Up</a>
    <a href="#content-2">About</a>
    <a href="#content-3">Projects</a>
    <a href="#content-4">Contact</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Esto lo puedes aplicar para elementos en especifico del dom, dime si te sirbio.